# Issue on Volley response

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to implement some code where I am fetching data from a server.
I used Volley response method to fetch the data.
I have a problem with that, I need if the response result is blank then the TextView will be shown otherwise the ListView will show.

Below is my code.

The log result is {"result":[]} if there is no data on the server

if I use `if(response.trim().length()==13)` condition. then it works properly

```
   private void sendRequest(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("***********","************");
                    Log.e("***********",response.trim());
                    Log.e("***********","************");
                    if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        tvMSG.setText("There is no history");
                        tvMSG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else{
                        showJSON(response);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MembershipHistory.this,error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

protected void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    Profile_Match_custom_Lists cl = new Profile_Match_custom_Lists(MembershipHistory.this, ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.ages, ParseJSON.heights, ParseJSON.communities,
            ParseJSON.castes,ParseJSON.educations,ParseJSON.occupations,ParseJSON.incomes,ParseJSON.pics,ParseJSON.locations,ParseJSON.shortlist,ParseJSON.expressinterest);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
}
```

And below is ParseJSON class

```
public class ParseJSON {

public static String[] ids;
public static String[] ages;
public static String[] heights;
public static String[] communities;
public static String[] castes;
public static String[] educations;
public static String[] occupations;
public static String[] incomes;
public static String[] pics;
public static String[] shortlist;
public static String[] expressinterest;
public static String[] locations;

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_AGE="age";
public static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "height";
public static final String KEY_COMMUNITY = "community";
public static final String KEY_CASTE = "caste";
public static final String KEY_EDUCATION = "education";
public static final String KEY_OCCUPATION = "occupation";
public static final String KEY_INCOME= "income";
public static final String KEY_PIC = "pic";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION="location";
public static final String KEY_EXPRESSINTEREST="expressinterest";
public static final String KEY_SHORTLIST="shortlist";


private JSONArray users = null;
private String json;
public ParseJSON(String json){
    this.json = json;
}

protected void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        ids = new String[users.length()];
        ages = new String[users.length()];
        heights = new String[users.length()];
        communities = new String[users.length()];
        castes = new String[users.length()];
        educations = new String[users.length()];
        occupations = new String[users.length()];
        incomes = new String[users.length()];
        pics = new String[users.length()];
        locations = new String[users.length()];
        shortlist = new String[users.length()];
        expressinterest = new String[users.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){

            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            ids[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
            ages[i] = jo.getString(KEY_AGE);
            heights[i] = jo.getString(KEY_HEIGHT);
            communities[i] = jo.getString(KEY_COMMUNITY);
            castes[i] = jo.getString(KEY_CASTE);
            educations[i] = jo.getString(KEY_EDUCATION);
            occupations[i] = jo.getString(KEY_OCCUPATION);
            incomes[i] = jo.getString(KEY_INCOME);
            pics[i] = jo.getString(KEY_PIC);
            locations[i] = jo.getString(KEY_LOCATION);
            shortlist[i] = jo.getString(KEY_SHORTLIST);
            expressinterest[i] = jo.getString(KEY_EXPRESSINTEREST);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The fact that you need to trim the response at all means something is wrong with the server sending extra whitespace

Comment: I have already used trim and if I used (response.length==13) this condition then its work properly because response length is 13. response= {"result":[]}

Comment: And you should really look into Gson or Jackson libraries

Comment: My point is that trim should not be needed. That depends on the server response, though. Which, if you have control over, should never send an empty String at all. Then you'd just use a JSONObjectRequest in Volley

Comment: You're checking the length of a string... Another thing that isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have received `{"result":[]}` from the server but comparing with empty string.

You should parse the response and check for empty array.

```
try {
    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray array = responseObject.getJSONArray("result");
    if(array.length() == 0){
        //no data
    } else{
        //use the data.
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also use `if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("{\"result\":[]}"))` instead of `if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))` but this approach is not recommended.

Comment: yes its working and response.length==13 also working but both is not look good as a professional

Comment: Did you try the edited answer?? It's been just a minute since I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`{"result":[]}` has 13 characters, sure.

However, that's not the same as an empty String, and is a poor condition if the `result` key ever changes, or the server response adds any whitespace character.

Besides,  your ParseJson class looks like it works fine when the results lists its empty. All the arrays will have 0 length. Therefore, the listview is empty.

You should use `setEmptyView` on the Listview if you would like to display something when there's no data

I would also suggest not using `static String[]` values, and you have define a `User` class, from which you can parse JSON into (ideally using a JSON library like Gson)

Comment: Means we should use view.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_list_item));

Comment: Assuming that `view` is a ListView instance, then yes

Answer (score 1):

Following changes Should work 
In `ParseJSON.java`

```
private JSONArray users = null;
private String json;
private int arraySize=-1
public ParseJSON(String json){
    this.json = json;
}
public int getArraySize(){
   return arraySize;
}
protected void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        arraySize=1; .......// rest of code will be same here
```

In your `onResponse(String response)` of volly implementation

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("***********","************");
                Log.e("***********",response.trim());
                Log.e("***********","************");
                ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
                pj.parseJSON();
                if(pj.getArraySize()>0){  // or ==1  whatever you like.
                    tvMSG.setText("There is no history");
                    tvMSG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else{
                    showJSON(pj);
                }
            }
```

Please do not forget to change your `showJSON(pj)` as following

```
protected void showJSON(ParseJSON pj){

    Profile_Match_custom_Lists cl = new Profile_Match_custom_Lists(MembershipHistory.this, ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.ages, ParseJSON.heights, ParseJSON.communities, ParseJSON.castes,ParseJSON.educations,ParseJSON.occupations,ParseJSON.incomes,ParseJSON.pics,ParseJSON.locations,ParseJSON.shortlist,ParseJSON.expressinterest);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
}
```

Happy Coding..